# error in calculating coordinates

Tags: c#, coordinates

My task is Coordinate Calculation, which is defined like:

1. Create the following data structure (`class` or `struct`):
   `cartCoordinate { double X; double Y, double Z }`
2. Create 4 random points from 1.
3. Calculate following:

   - Distance in 3D between 2 Points
   - Extent of the quadrangle

I have written the code, but am still not getting the  correct results.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class cartCoordinate
    {
        double x, y, z;
        cartCoordinate(double a ,double b ,double c)
        {
            x = a;
            y = b;
            z = c;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double X=1, Y=2, Z=3;   // Randome numbers
            Console.WriteLine("First random points are    " + X + " " + Y + " " + Z);
           cartCoordinate obj1 = new cartCoordinate(X,Y,Z);

           X = 8; Y = 12; Z = 5;   // Randome numbers
           Console.WriteLine("Second random points are   " + X + " " + Y + " " + Z);
           cartCoordinate obj2 = new cartCoordinate(X, Y, Z);

           X = 10; Y = 2 ; Z = 6;   // Randome numbers
           Console.WriteLine("Third random points are    " + X + " " + Y + " " + Z);
            cartCoordinate obj3 = new cartCoordinate(X, Y, Z);

            X = 19; Y = 12; Z = 9;   // Randome numbers
           Console.WriteLine("Forth random points are    " + X + " " + Y + " " + Z);
           cartCoordinate obj4 = new cartCoordinate(X, Y, Z);

           Console.WriteLine("Choose any two point");
           int a, b;
           a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
           b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
           switch ((a * 10) + b)
           {
               case 12: Console.WriteLine("Distance is " + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((obj2.x - obj1.x), 2) + Math.Pow((obj2.y - obj1.y), 2) + Math.Pow((obj2.z - obj1.z), 2)));
                   break;
               case 13: Console.WriteLine("Distance is " + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((obj3.x - obj1.x), 2) + Math.Pow((obj3.y - obj1.y), 2) + Math.Pow((obj3.z - obj1.z), 2)));
                   break;
               case 23: Console.WriteLine("Distance is " + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((obj3.x - obj2.x), 2) + Math.Pow((obj3.y - obj2.y), 2) + Math.Pow((obj3.z - obj2.z), 2)));
                   break;
           }
           Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "not getting result" - can you specify exactly what wrong?

Comment: You would learn a lot if you could get the mods to migrate this to Code Review - there are a ton of improvements you could make.

Comment: what is the problem with the code?

Comment: the problem is that I don't know why it is not calculating the distance between 2 distance. It asks me to select two values and then nothing appears

Comment: try debugging: put a breakpoint (with F9) on the line where the program asks user for input. then you can step to the next lines using F10. while the program is stopped, you can see your variables' values by hovering your mouse over them

Comment: @JamesMcLeod, I see. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should, create your own class/structure `Vector3D` and define a method `float GetDistance(Vector3D va, Vector3D va)`, then create the instances of this class/structure and use this method.

```
class Vector3D
{
    public float X;
    public float Y;
    public float Z;

    public static float GetDistance(Vector3D va, Vector3D vb)
    {
        if ((va == null) || (vb == null))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Params are null.");
            return 0f;
        }

        return Math.Sqrt((va.X * va.X  - vb.X * vb.X) + (va.Y * va.Y  - vb.Y * vb.Y) + (va.Z * va.Z  - vb.Z * vb.Z));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the swicth. Replace your switch with this one

```
switch ((a * 10) + b) {
    case 12:
        Console.WriteLine("Distance is " + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((obj2.x - obj1.x), 2) + Math.Pow((obj2.y - obj1.y), 2) + Math.Pow((obj2.z - obj1.z), 2)));
        break;
    case 13:
        Console.WriteLine("Distance is " + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((obj3.x - obj1.x), 2) + Math.Pow((obj3.y - obj1.y), 2) + Math.Pow((obj3.z - obj1.z), 2)));
        break;
    case 23:
        Console.WriteLine("Distance is " + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((obj3.x - obj2.x), 2) + Math.Pow((obj3.y - obj2.y), 2) + Math.Pow((obj3.z - obj2.z), 2)));
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("None of them");
}
```